# "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause" when generating ms Access table using DDL in C#

Tags: ms-access, ddl

I am getting this error when generating a Access database table using DDL. I am not very familiar with this sort of stuff so help will be appreciated.

```
_SqlString = "CREATE TABLE QuestionStatID("
                            + "StatID VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,"
                            + "Username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,"
                            + "answerDate VARCHAR(25),"
                            + "Timetaken int,"
                            + "Score int,"
                            + "Difficulty int,"
                            + "PRIMARY KEY(StatID),"
                            + "FOREIGN KEY(Username)"
                            + ")";
```

Comment: Documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql. You need `CHAR` instead of `varchar(25)` and you need to specify `CONSTRAINT` with a name, and the `FOREIGN KEY` needs to say which table it references (that is also for standard SQL

Answer (score 0):

Jet/SQL has a different syntax to use. First it has TEXT instead of VARCHAR fields and then the relationship is stated using CONSTRAINT. So, your query should be something like this.  Assuming the presence of a *userstable* and a field on that table that you want to use as the primary key to reference.

(Tested with the SQL pane in LinqPad, not in a real C# program)

```
CREATE TABLE QuestionStat
(
   QuestionStatID TEXT(50) CONSTRAINT QuestionStatIDPK PRIMARY KEY, 
   Username TEXT(25) CONSTRAINT usernameFK REFERENCES userstable (unique_field_on_userstable)
   answerDate TEXT(25),
   Timetaken int,
   Score int,
   Difficulty int
)
```

Notice that the table referenced needs to have a unique index on the field linked with the constraint.